# Can't locate Cairo.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

I'm new to perl and I try to run a script that uses Cairo package.
When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Can't locate Cairo.pm in @INC
```

So, I tried to install it and it appears to already be installed:

```
?> sudo yum install cairo-devel
Package cairo-devel-1.8.8-3.fc12.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I tried to find the file `Cairo.pm` manualy (using `find -name Cairo.pm`) but couldn't find it.

Finally, I've tried to find it using `rpm -ql cairo-devel` and also couldn't find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of perl are you using? Any chance you've installed a perl in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: The perl version is: v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi.  I don't think the perl is installed where you mentioned (This dir has only 4 files in it)

Comment: `which perl` will tell you. Although I've just noticed - you've installed cairo-devel, but that doesn't necessarily include perl modules. Try `cpan install Cairo`

Comment: Ok it says /usr/bin/perl

Comment: @Sobrique it would be `cpan Cairo`, not `cpan install Cairo`. I make that mistake all the time myself.

Comment: Works on my linux box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some confusion about RPMs here.

- The RPM that contains the Cairo library is called `cairo`
- The RPM that contains the headers that you need in order to use Cairo in C programs is called `cairo-dev`

In order to use Cairo from Perl you will need to install the CPAN module [Cairo.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cairo). That may be pre-packaged for your distribution in an RPM called `perl-Cairo`. But you may need to install it using [`cpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN/scripts/cpan) (or, better if you have it, [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm)).